# convert pandas dataframe to utf8

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

How to convert pandas dataframe to unicode?

```
`messages=pandas.read_csv('data/SMSSpamCollection',sep='\t',quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE,names=["label", "message"])
def split_into_tokens(message):
  message = unicode(message, 'utf8')  # convert bytes into proper unicode
  return TextBlob(message).words


messages.head().apply(split_into_tokens(messages))`
```

It gives error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "minor.py", line 46, in <module>
messages.head().apply(split_into_tokens(messages))
File "minor.py", line 42, in split_into_tokens
message = unicode(message, 'utf8')  # convert bytes into proper unicode
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, DataFrame found
```

Comment: try messages.head().apply(split_into_tokens) and run and make sure the 'apply' do not work on whole dataframe you need to pass df['column_name'].apply(some_function)

Comment: I am adding it as answer then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the code

```
messages.head().apply(split_into_tokens(messages))
```

to

```
messages.head().apply(split_into_tokens)
```

while using 'apply' with a funtion like in your case passing parameters is not required, as your code shows it is passing a dataframe which is giving error on execution.

Answer (score 9):

Df.x.str.encode('utf-8')

Will fix your problems.

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.encode.html